# Git with SCM Manager

Tags: git, scmmanager

I have a problem with users managment in SCM Manager, when I add users in repository permessions and I go to make clone, push or pull, the only valid password is "scmadmin" (the admin password !), I need your help and also totorials about git with scm-manager.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The admin user "scmadmin" has full access to all repositories. So I think you forgot to set permissions for your new created user at the repository. Go to the repositories tab and select the repository you want to configure. At the bottom area select the "Permissions" tab and add your user with "write" or "owner" access level.

The SCM-Manager handles your request like any other git repository server. So work as usual with it. For a special SCM-Manager tutorial (not depending on git) see the link Thomas already posted.